# Avoid changing color of my flag when hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a flag for marking some rows.

I have the following css

```
<table class="hovered no-border" data-url="@Url.Action("General", "Transport")">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>
            <td>TNB.12/00125</td>
            <td><i class="icon-flag-3 fg-color-grayLight"></i> Blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>
            <td>TNB.12/00128</td>
            <td><i class="icon-flag-3 fg-color-grayLight"></i> Blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>
            <td>TNB.12/00129</td>
            <td><i class="icon-flag-3 fg-color-grayLight"></i> Blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"/></td>
            <td>TNB.12/00119</td>
            <td><i class="icon-flag-3 fg-color-yellow"></i> Blah blah blah</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

table.hovered tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: #ececec; 
}
table.hovered tbody tr td:hover i {
  color: #9a9a9a !important;
}

[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  font-family: 'iconFont';
  font-style: normal;
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  margin: 0 2px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  border: 1px transparent solid;
}
.icon-flag-3:before {
   content: "\e14f";
}
```

[image]

When a row is hovered, I change the color of the flag from grayLight to a darken gray. This is done with my css.

As you can see the line #119 is decorated with a yellow flag.

**My problem:** I don't want to change the color of the yellow flag when the row is hovered. How to avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: Ok so impossible only with css?

Comment: Could you post the classes for `icon-flag` and it's `hover` state (if exists)

Comment: It looks like we're missing code. Where is the code that determines the over state of `icon-flag`?

Comment: I updated my question to show the css for icon-flag

Comment: Just write one more rule specific for yellow-flag, meta-example: http://jsfiddle.net/hZfkr/

Comment: Thanks dfsq your solution was ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would just overwrite the color of the grey flag like this:

```
table.hovered tbody tr td:hover i.fg-color-grayLight {
  color: #9a9a9a !important;
}
```